# Probability of revealing two cards with the same rank

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A deck of 52 cards (13 ranks and 4 suits) is randomly shuffled, then split into two piles of 26 cards. Player A and play B each own one of the two piles. They both reveal the top of their piles simultaneously. What is the probability of the two revealed cards have the same rank?

My thought is: what player A reveals doesn't matter, and player B just needs to reveal the same rank. The expected number of cards with that same rank going into player B's pile is $\frac{1}{2}*4=2$ (total 4 cards of the same rank, each chance of going into player B's pile is $\frac{1}{2}$). The chance of that revealed card in player B's pile being the same rank is, therefore, $\frac{2}{26}$. Could I know if my reasoning is correct, or is there exists any overcounting or undercounting? And if mine is wrong, could I know how to correctly approach this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are three cards of the same rank as $A's$ so...

Comment: @lulu yeah I am thinking this also. But is that reasonable to first have a check how many same rank cards will go to player B's deck?  Say If player A's pile is 42 number of cards, but player B's pile is 10 number of cards, then I think player B won't have the chance of having that all 3 remaining same ranks.

Comment: $B's$ pile has nothing to do with it...the card $B$ reveals is equally likely to be any of the other $51$ cards.  This would be true even if $A$ and $B$ started with piles of different sizes.

Comment: @lulu Got it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is that we know one of the cards of that rank is in $A$'s pile.  There are now $3$ cards of that rank among the $51$ cards left.  The expected number in $B$'s pile is then $\frac {3\cdot 26}{51}$, which is a little greater than $1\frac 12$.  The chance a particular card of $A$'s is matched is $\frac 3{51}=\frac 1{17}$ because there are $51$ unknown cards, of which $3$ match.

Comment: Thank you. Just wanna make sure that the expected value is $1\frac{1}{2}$, but it has nothing to do with the probability right? We just simply think there are 3 remaining cards with the same rank out of the remaining 51 cards. So the probability is simply $\frac{3}{51}=\frac{1}{17}$.

Answer (score 2):

Equivalently, you can consider shuffling the deck and comparing the first two cards:
$$
\frac{\text{# of ways to shuffle deck so first 2 cards have same rank}}{\text{# of ways to shuffle deck}}
=\frac{13\cdot4\cdot3\cdot50!}{52!}
=\frac{1}{17}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Actually the question can be reworded as:

"I draw a card (that I do not replace) and after that again I draw a card. What is the probability that both drawn cards are of the same rank?"

There is *no essential difference*, and it is a good thing to get hold of that.

So try to do that, for instance by searching for an essential difference.

This search wil be in vain, but not fruitless: it provides in an improved intuition concerning probabilities.

---

After drawing the first card there are $51$ cards left and among them there are $3$ that have the same rank, so the probability that such a card is drawn as second is $\frac3{51}=\frac1{17}$

Comment: Thank you very much! A very straightforward and strong answer. That is what I learn and realize now.

Comment: You are very welcome.